# How can I hang a large mirror on an uneven (warped?) wall?

Tags: drywall, mounting

I'm in the process of trying to assemble an exercise room in my home. Of the four walls, only one is continuous without any windows or doors so I've chosen to make it the 'mirror wall' and fill the length of it with mirrors. As the wall is 12' long, I can perfectly fit 4x 36x60" mirrors in portrait orientation.

These are borderless mirrors and are supported by screw-in clips on the top and bottom. They are being mounted to drywall.

I mounted the first mirror without any trouble, but when hanging the second I was frustrated by the difficulty in getting the top/bottom corners of the second mirror to align with the first. I then realized that the wall was slightly warped (I don't know a better term) such that when looking at the edge of the first mirror, it first appeared that the mirror was bowing out away from the wall, but I then recognized that the wall itself was bowing away from the mirror. I simply mounted the second mirror as close to perfectly as I could and moved on.

My problem now is the third mirror. This section of the wall is so warped that if I hold an inflexible object against it horizontally (such as a level), it will rock back and forth and I am unable to get the leftmost and rightmost corners of the object to lay flat at the same time. I haven't measured the curvature of the wall, but I'd estimate that it's curving maybe 5 degrees. I tried mounting the third mirror in spite of this flaw and due to rigidity of the mirror, if I slid it into the left 'clip', it would not fit into the right 'clip'. I tried to force it into position and the strain was so great that it ripped one clip straight out of the drywall.

Without completely removing and fixing the wall, is there any way for me to secure these mirrors while still keeping them borderless/frameless? If they were mounted in a frame, I could just use framing wire (unsure of the proper name) so that the mirror itself would not be affixed to the wall and it would instead be freehanging, but I don't think that is an option in the absence of a frame. I was considering somehow raising the rightmost clip by cutting a very small piece of wood to act as a spacer between the drywall and the clip, bringing it into alignment with the leftmost clip, but determining the thickness of the wood seems tricky.

Comment: Shimming can be tricky, but for such a tall mirror, you have to remember that if only the top corner is supported away from the wall, there's nothing supporting the middle of the mirror.  If someone tripped and hit the wall, or just leaned against it not knowing, the mirror could crack and you'd have a... bad situation.  In other words, you're going to need a lot more that 4 supports if the mirror isn't touching the wall.

Comment: Good point - I can't install side clips since the wall is just long enough for four mirrors, but each mirror has 3 clips on the top and 3 clips on the bottom at 6", 18", and 30".

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply install washers behind the clips to act as standoffs. Be sure your screws are long and stout enough. Use washers as needed to create a small gap behind the mirrors at all mounting points, allowing alignment between mirrors.

This could create a visual bounce/jiggle effect if the mirrors aren't stiff enough. Use balls of poster putty or other flexible material at several places across the backs of the mirrors to act as anchor supports. This will also provide structural support in the event of an accidental collision.

Comment: I like the idea of washers - I can incrementally add a few to get to a good 'just about' distance from the wall. I'll give this a try tonight and see how well it works out. I was thinking about putting something behind the mirrors to fill in the gaps but I wasn't sure of a suitable material. Putty makes perfect sense!